# Ember - Autosave with JSON fields

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model (using Ember Data) that I would like to autosave whenever any of the fields change. I have been using [this autosave plugin](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-autosave) and it works great, ***except*** that I have JSON fields that do not trigger the autosave.

My model has fields that look like this:

```
title: DS.attr('string'),
options: DS.attr(),
```

Whenever the `title` attribute changes, it will trigger the `setUnknownProperty` method on the `ObjectProxy` used by the ember-autosave plugin. However, if I change, for example, `options.layout`, `setUnknownProperty` does not get called, so it won't trigger the autosave.

One alternative I tried was to set observers on all the properties in the `options` object. However, once I save the model to the database, Ember gets data back from the server and reloads the model, which then fires the observers again, resulting in another save, causing an infinite loop.

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 1):

What if you do

```
options.layout = 'foobar';
```

Then immediately call:

```
  this.set('options', options)
```

Will this trigger  the setUnknownProperty method in your objectProxy?

Comment: Hm. I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: This ended up solving my problem in a roundabout way. I didn't have to trigger `this.set('options', options);`, I just triggered `this.set('changed', 'changed');` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Awesome. What is changed? Is that a built in ember thing?

Comment: Nope, just an artibrary field on the ObjectProxy to trigger the autosave.